# How to detect if a point intersect body in libgdx

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I am adding bodies with fixtures to a box2d world in libgdx.
I want to detect if the user has touched (clicked) an object.
How do I do this? thanks

Comment: Are you using stage in combination with box2d bodies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use libgdx [Stage](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html) in order to detect touch events on Actors (what you are referring to them as Objects here). The best practice is to map a box2d body to a stage actor which makes it quite simple to do things like that.

**To detect touch:**

Implement touchDown method of the [InputProcessor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) interface such that:

- You have to transform your screen coordinates to stage coordinates using stage.toStageCoordiantes(...) method.
- Use the transformed coordinates to detect hit on the Actor (Object) on stage using stage.hit(x, y).
- stage.hit(x, y) will return you the actor if a hit is detected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a way I can detect clicks on objects without using the scene API? Currently, i am just using libgdx to add bodies with fixtures to a box2d world. And I am using the box2ddebugrenderer. Thanks!

Comment: Box2d is purely a 2D Physics Engine. You cannot use it to process touch events. You will have to use some other means such as the one suggested in the answer to register touch events. Kindly check out this package: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks.Can I use box2d to detect if a point is inside a box or fixture? If so, how? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

User touches the body only if he touches some of `Fixture`'s contained into this body. This mean, you can check every `Fixture` of `Body` using `testPoit()` method:

```
public class Player {
    private Body _body;

    public boolean isPointOnPlayer(float x, float y){
        for(Fixture fixture : _body.getFixtureList())
            if(fixture.testPoint(x, y)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Next, you need to create [`InputAdapter`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputAdapter.html) like this:

```
public class PlayerControl extends InputAdapter {
    private final Camera _camera;
    private final Player _player;
    private final Vector3 _touchPosition;

    public PlayerControl(Camera camera, Player player) {
        _camera = camera;
        _player = player;
        // create buffer vector to make garbage collector happy
        _touchPosition = new Vector3();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // don't forget to unproject screen coordinates to game world
        _camera.unproject(_touchPosition.set(screenX, screenY, 0F));
        if (_player.isPointOnPlayer(_touchPosition.x, _touchPosition.y)) {
            // touch on the player body. Do some stuff like player jumping
            _player.jump();
            return true;
        } else
            return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }
}
```

And the last one - setup this processor to listen user input:

```
public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void create () {
    // prepare player and game camera
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new PlayerControl(cam, player));
}
```

Read more about touch handling [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mouse%2C-touch-%26-keyboard#touch-point)